# How to edit source/SQL statement for Excel Query in c#

Tags: c#, excel, odbc

I have been having an ongoing issue where I cannot edit the value of the source for my query. I have tried using the Excel.WorkbookConnection.ODBCConnection property, but it always throws a generica exception which is HRESTULT: 0x800A03EC. The reason I put SQL Source in the title is because if you go to the data source settings, the source I am trying to change is under SQL Source. Just FYI

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Excel.Application XLApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook XLSourceWB = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(SourceFile);
Excel.WorkbookConnection connectionBS = XLSourceWB.Connections[2]; // The first connection that needs to be changed
System.Console.WriteLine(connectionBS.Name); //Returns the correct name
```

Here are screenshots of the steps that I am trying to automate:

[First go to the Query Tab, then click Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS5dR.png)

[Then click Advanced Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PqCK.png)

[Then I need to change one of the parameters in the first source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxNvT.png)

Any input helps!

Thank you!